# What will be locked when I use mysql transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm confused about the mysql transaction. I have a table as follow.

```
content  ip              status
aaa      null            wait
bbb      192.168.21.11   processing
ccc      null            wait
ddd      192.168.21.11   processing
eee      192.168.21.12   processing
```

I have two processes running on two different machines to deal with this table. Each of them is doing the following operations.
(1) select a "wait" content from the table
(2) count the contents on each ip and select the ip with fewer contents
(3) update the content status to processing and set the ip column.

I used to use table locks to avoid race conditions, but it causes deadlocks. So now I want to use transactions instead. But I'm confused about the locking scope of the transaction.

I can use "for update" to avoid the race condition when two processes select a wait content from the table and update it to processing. But how should I  avoid the race condition from occurring when counting and updating to processing? In the example above, both processes get 1 with 192.168.21.12 and both choose it for the process, then the content on this ip will be 3.

Do all the queries in a transaction execute atomically, so that no race conditions occur? Or mysql just locks the rows between "select ... for update" and "commit"?

Comment: which engine you are using in table definition?

Comment: I'm using innodb.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL Innodb, the locks hold by transaction are released when transaction commit or rollback. In above case, the lock granted in step 1, would be hold until transaction complete.

The transaction are not run atomically, they could run concurrently if they do not touch the same records, otherwise, a transaction has to wait another transaction release the locks.

Regarding which kind of locks would be hold by statement, you could refer [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have another question. I saw documents say that "start transaction" will autometically set autocommit=0, but I want to know that if "commit" autometically sets autocommit=1.

Comment: No, "start transaction" will start a new transaction, which does not affect the value of "autocommit". You could test it with a Mysql client. see [autocommit, Commit, and Rollback](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-autocommit-commit-rollback.html)

Comment: Use `select @@autocommit;`  to see the current value.